# Ethernet is detected but my portal keeps on loading

Tags: internet, ethernet, ubuntu-drivers

$ lspci | grep --ignore-case "Ethernet"
O/p: 08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek semiconductor co.,LTD. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)

I have recently booted my hp PC with Ubuntu 18.04.2 and the internet is not working now although it was working fine with Windows 10.Whenever i try to load my portal following message appears. since i wasn't able to add pictures over here so i added a link to reddit...please guys help me out:

[Reddit Post:Ubuntu ethernet Problem](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/b9i8yo/ubuntu_ethernet_problem/)

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `ifconfig` or `ip addr`. How is your network wired? Are you cable or DSL? Do you use VPN? Do you have a router with access control?

Comment: @heynnema:  ...I wasn't able to add pictures here. so i created a reddit post. will u please help me out. [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/b9i8yo/ubuntu_ethernet_problem/)

Comment: You didn't answer any of my information requests from my last comment. You can post images at imgur.com and then post the link here. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema I have answered your question...in that Reddit link

Comment: Oops... maybe I should scroll the page down huh? My bad. Sorry. You still haven't answered all of my questions though. All is saw there was the lshw command output. Do this quick test... UNPLUG your router/modem from AC power. Shutdown your computer. PLUG your router/modem back into AC power, count to 30, then power up your computer. See if things work now.

Comment: @heynnema Actually I am using hostel's lanport...from there I'm joining my PC to lanport through Ethernet cable

Comment: I switched off my computer... reinserted Ethernet cable...still not working

Comment: Another test... it looks like you can get wireless, yes? Unplug the ethernet cable, use FIREFOX, and try and reach your portal.

Comment: Through my mobile data I can go wireless

Comment: Is that where the 192 address is coming from, a tethered mobile phone? Please briefly describe this portal... do you log into it before being able to access the rest of the Internet? Reconnect the ethernet cable, and try FIREFOX to get to your portal.

Comment: Okay...I am residing in hotel...there we are provided with lan port...we just need to connect a Ethernet cable and attach it to our PC...then we need to go to portal...n get logged in...after that we r able to use internet....I tried to reconnect my Ethernet cable...using Firefox tried to reach my portal and the page response is "The connection has timed out "

Comment: Ah, I understand. Who gave you the portal address and port #? The hotel? Can you try a different portal port?

Comment: Sorry it was hostel not hotel...my portal address was given to us by our University

Comment: I think the port is fine... because the Ethernet was never a problem while using Windows 10

Comment: $ ifconfig
enp8s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
       inet 172.16.168.201  netmask 255.255.254.0  broadcast 172.16.169.255
       inet6 fe80::a74a:5e06:ea15:d99f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
       ether 6c:c2:17:ea:6a:5c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
       RX packets 7661  bytes 895305 (895.3 KB)
       RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
       TX packets 2930  bytes 226086 (226.0 KB)
       TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
       inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
       inet6 ::1  p

Comment: lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
       inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
       inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
       loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
       RX packets 63655  bytes 4830241 (4.8 MB)
       RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
       TX packets 63655  bytes 4830241 (4.8 MB)
       TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Comment: The fact that it works in Windows really has little importance when we talk about Ubuntu. I'm missing something here. I'd still like to try another hostel LAN port. If that doesn't work, you should contact the University's IT dept for further help.